# In an Async task does constructor runs first of doInBackground?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am just using a simple logic to get to contact name (you all can see in the code below using if statement) .But that if statement is not working .The problem is i am comparing string s1 which is the contact person name with s2 which i am getting it from the constructor and i am supremely confident that s1 contains the same as s2.So which runs first constructor or do in background ?.Coz if doInBackground then i need to make the parameter global and not to pass in this method.

```
private class findContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {
    String contactName;
    public findContacts(String contactName) {
        this.contactName = contactName;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null);

        String name = null,phoneNumber=null;

        if (phones != null) {
            while (phones.moveToNext())
            {
                name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));



                System.out.println("1st name "+name.toLowerCase()+" 2nd name"+contactName.toLowerCase()+" both are same ?"+name.toLowerCase().contains(contactName.toLowerCase()));

                if (name.toLowerCase().equals(contactName.toLowerCase())){   // The problem lies here 
                    System.out.println(name+" "+phoneNumber);
                    phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                }else {
                   // newPhoneNum="123456";
                }

            }

            phones.close();
        }
        return phoneNumber;

    }
```

[image]

Comment: constructor always runs first (except static methods)

Answer (score 2):

`AsyncTask#doInBackground()` only get called once you called `execute()` on its object . Thats how its works asynchronously . it will ofcourse called after constructor . Debug your code inside `doInBackground`.

NOTE:- You can also call `doInBackground()` directly just like some normal non-static method but this will not make any sense cause this way it will not get call asynchronously. 
Your calling should be as :

`new findContacts ("Alice").execute()`.

Class name should be `FindContacts` not `findContacts`([Java naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)).

Comment: can you please take a look at the  logs. i have no idea why its not showing true

Comment: can you please look through the logs and tell me ,there are 500+contacts,debugging will not a good use

Comment: so fool of me , i was using replace for getting the contactName  so I ignored white spaces ie the contactName =" sandeep" and name = "sandeep". That's why it was not workng. But out of curiosity .contains() should work ?

Answer (score 1):

Instructions inside the constructor are executed before all other instructions just after instantiation. The doInBackground is called when you execute the async task.